# How to erase things from tablelayout?

Tags: android, tablelayout, tablerow

I used a Tablelayout in my application and i added some couple of TableRows.
And i want every time i press a button to delete the TableRows i added before.How is it possible?Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

row = (TableRow)findViewById(R.id.row);
table.removeView(row);

Answer (score 0):

```
TableLayout tblLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(viewID);
tblLayout.removeAllViews();
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do so it would be setting the row gone.

```
TableLayout tableLayout = findByViewId(R.layout.myTL);
tableLayout.getChildAt(numberOfRow).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Hope this solution fits your case!